# web Routes doesn't working without php artisan in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, routes

im new in laravel so im just try to run laravel without php artisan and read much topics about run laravel without php artisan but the main problem is the main route (/) is working and run (home view) but other routes like (/about) in web file doesnt work. so how can i run other views via routes (web file)?? i tried many ways for run laravel without php artisan but im stuck in this part routes. without routes, laravel is completely useless. i moved index.php from public folder and .htaccess to the root folder for run laravel wihout php artisan like this:[root folder laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u269D.png)
and this my index.php so i changed it to run from root not public folder:
[index.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsNdY.png)
and .htaccess:
[.htacess file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y1HA.png)
and finally this is my web file which is my routes:
[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcYg0.png)
when i set routes about and try to go to that, the error 404 is shown up: [error 404 /about route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd9xi.png)
so how can i set routes and actualy the main problem is how can i request and Recieve urls from root without php artisan. and another way that i tried is rename server.php to index .php and i could say none of this ways are working. it just show the root home page not working for other routs. thanks

Comment: so what webserver are you using? this is a misconfiguration of your server, in regards to Pretty URLs ... and the webroot/docroot of the site should be pointing to the `public` folder, there is no need to move anything around

Comment: im using apache and i want run laravel on root of localhost. dont want run via php artisan. but other routes not working.

Comment: set the docroot/webroot of the site to the `public` folder ... then you have to make sure that your site in apache is configured to allow the .htaccess file to override

Comment: ok man thank you so much. beacause im newbie and didnt understand what was going on. i didnt know well  apache, so i did things you said , and laravel works fine.